# How do I clear the form fields after submission in this Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I am working a small book-list app with Vue 3 and the composition API.

In App.vue I have:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    import Book from './Book.vue'
    import AddBook from './AddBook.vue'

    const books = ref([])

    const addBook = function(newBook) {
      books.value.push(newBook);
    }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="display-4">Reading list for 2024</h1>
    <ol v-if="books.length" class="books">
      <Book v-for="(book, index) in books" :book="{
        title: book.title,
        author: book.author
      }" />
    </ol>
    <p class="text-center" v-else>No books to display</p>

     <AddBook @add-book="addBook" />
  </div>
</template>
```

In `Book.vue` I have:

```
<script setup>
 defineProps({
  book: Object
})
</script>

<template>
  <li>
    <i>{{ book.title }}</i> by  {{ book.author }} 
    <span class="delete" @click="$emit('delete-book', index)">&#x2716</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

The form for adding a book is in `AddBook.vue`:

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, defineEmits } from 'vue'
  const emit = defineEmits(['add-book'])

  const isValid = ref(true);

  const newBook = {
    title: '',
    author: ''
  }

  const handleSubmit = function(){
    isValid.value = false;
    if(newBook.title.length && newBook.author.length){
     isValid.value = true;
      emit('add-book', newBook);
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
<h2 class="display-4">Add a book</h2>
 <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
  <div v-if="!isValid" class="p-2 text-center alert alert-danger">
    The form data is invalid!
  </div>
  <div class="mb-2">
    <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
    <input id="title" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" v-model="newBook.title">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mb-2">
    <label for="author" class="form-label">Author</label>
    <input id="author" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" v-model="newBook.author">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-2">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w-100" type="submit">Add</button>  
  </div>
 </form>
</template>
```

#### The goal

After adding a book, I want the *form fields to be cleared*.

#### The problem

Doing this in order to achieve the goal does clear the fields, but it also empties the `title` and `author` properties of the `newBook` object:

```
emit('add-book', newBook);
// Clear fields
newBook.title = '',
newBook.author = ''
```

##### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `newBook` is cleared before the parent component has a change to access it.

You could create a copy of the `newBook` object before emitting:

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, defineEmits } from 'vue'
  const emit = defineEmits(['add-book']);

  const isValid = ref(true);

  const newBook = {
    title: '',
    author: ''
  }

  const handleSubmit = function(){
    isValid.value = false;
    if(newBook.title.length && newBook.author.length){
      isValid.value = true;

      // Create a copy of newBook before emitting
      const bookCopy = { ...newBook };
      emit('addBook', bookCopy);
      
      // Clear the original newBook object
      newBook.author = '';
      newBook.title = '';
    }
  }
</script>
```